# Cannot get KeyPressEventHandler in usercontrol

Tags: c#, user-controls

From the site that I saw on how to create a user control of keypad [Click here for the link](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/176782-building-an-application-poscash-register-part-one/)

. I successfully added the control in the tools. and drag one in the Form UI. when i start clicking the number. the RaiseButton is triggered:

```
private void btn1_click(object sender,eventargs e)
  {
      RaiseButton('1');
  }
```

and on the other usercontrol.
There is this method

```
public event KeyPressHandler IsPressed;

public void RaiseButton(char Tosend)
{
    KeyPressEventHandler handle = IsPressed;
    handle(this,new KeypressEventArgs(Tosend));
}
```

The Class KeyPressHandler Ispressed value is null
  so it cannot write to textbox. Now my question is, did I miss something that makes keypresseventhandler null?

Please advise thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it now. I was so stupid the event that I used in the form is not the same event that I used in the user control. The `public event KeyPressEventHandler IsPressed` event in the user control must be use also in your form. To be able to register this one, On your form where your you want to use the control. Click the user Control and look in the event property or just click the thunder symbol in your property. Look for the event **IsPressed** and now your good to go. double click and put the code that you want to do for the event. @wlemond thanks for giving me the example.

Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

The IsPressed event is null because nothing is registered for it. Once you register for that event it will no longer be null. Check for the event being null first. Also, you don't need to assign it to a variable.

```C#
public void RaiseButton(char Tosend)
{
    if (IsPressed != null)
    {
        IsPressed(this,txtbox.text);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick response but what do you mean by nothing registered for it? on this line  public event KeypressEventHandler IsPressed -- the value of this null already. How can i Register this event?

Comment: and sorry i edit the code here  handle(this, txtbox.text) to 
handle(this,new KeyPresseventargs(tosend)); this is in the windows control library.

Comment: It seems like you aren't quite grasping how events in C# work. I've created a simple example for you here.
https://dotnetfiddle.net/3PfsRJ

It might help you understand what you need to do in your code. Also, you may want to see this page.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645739%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

I'm guessing by your name that you code in Java. C# events are a bit different from how Java does it.

Comment: @welmond Thanks for that example. If you saw the link that i gave on my question "click for the link". I just saw it there and tried it. I was able to run it successfully before and when I try to make another one. I failed already. This is what makes me confused. That was working before and now I can't even make it work.